# Calculating Great-Circle Distance with SQLite

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, geospatial, haversine

Here is my problem, I have a SQLite table with locations and latitudes / longitudes. Basically I need to:

```
SELECT location, HAVERSINE(lat, lon) AS distance FROM location ORDER BY distance ASC;
```

**`HAVERSINE()` is a PHP function** that should return the [**Great-Circle Distance**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) (in miles or km) given a pair of latitude and longitude values. **One of these pairs should be provided by PHP and the other pair should be provided by each latitude / longitude row** available in the `locations` table.

Since SQLite doesn't has any Geo Spatial extension (*<s>AFAIK</s> [SpatiaLite](http://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite/) exists but still...*) I'm guessing the best approach would be to use a custom function with either one of the PDO methods:

- [`PDO::sqliteCreateFunction()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pdo-sqlitecreatefunction.php)
- [`PDO::sqliteCreateAggregate()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pdo-sqlitecreateaggregate.php)

I think for this case `PDO::sqliteCreateFunction()` would be enough, however my limited experience with this function can be reduced to usage cases similar to the one provided in the PHP Manual:

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:geo.db');

function md5_and_reverse($string) { return strrev(md5($string)); }

$db->sqliteCreateFunction('md5rev', 'md5_and_reverse', 1);
$rows = $db->query('SELECT md5rev(filename) FROM files')->fetchAll();
```

I'm having some trouble figuring out how can I get an SQLite user defined function to **process data from PHP and table data at the same time** and I would appreciate if someone could help me solve this problem while also understanding SQLite UDFs (a big win of SQLite IMO) a little bit better.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a way that will work without defining custom functions? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126830/query-to-get-records-based-on-radius-in-sqlite

Comment: @Pentium10: No, not a fast one at least. Check my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096385/formulas-to-calculate-geo-proximity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your "interesting link".

```
function sqlite3_distance_func($lat1,$lon1,$lat2,$lon2) {
    // convert lat1 and lat2 into radians now, to avoid doing it twice below
    $lat1rad = deg2rad($lat1);
    $lat2rad = deg2rad($lat2);
    // apply the spherical law of cosines to our latitudes and longitudes, and set the result appropriately
    // 6378.1 is the approximate radius of the earth in kilometres
    return acos( sin($lat1rad) * sin($lat2rad) + cos($lat1rad) * cos($lat2rad) * cos( deg2rad($lon2) - deg2rad($lon1) ) ) * 6378.1;
}

$db->sqliteCreateFunction('DISTANCE', 'sqlite3_distance_func', 4);
```

Then do  a query with:

```
"SELECT * FROM location ORDER BY distance(latitude,longitude,{$lat},{$lon}) LIMIT 1"
```

---

**EDIT (by QOP):** I finally needed this again and this solution worked out great, I just ended up modifying the code a bit to it is a bit less verbose and handles non-numeric values gracefully, here it is:

```
$db->sqliteCreateFunction('distance', function () {
    if (count($geo = array_map('deg2rad', array_filter(func_get_args(), 'is_numeric'))) == 4) {
        return round(acos(sin($geo[0]) * sin($geo[2]) + cos($geo[0]) * cos($geo[2]) * cos($geo[1] - $geo[3])) * 6378.14, 3);
    }

    return null;
}, 4);
```

Comment: Does this function return in miles or kilometers?

Comment: Is there a JavaScript version?

Answer (score 9):

So far I could only think of this solution:

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:geo.db');

$db->sqliteCreateFunction('ACOS', 'acos', 1);
$db->sqliteCreateFunction('COS', 'cos', 1);
$db->sqliteCreateFunction('RADIANS', 'deg2rad', 1);
$db->sqliteCreateFunction('SIN', 'sin', 1);
```

And then execute the following lengthy query:

```
SELECT "location",
       (6371 * ACOS(COS(RADIANS($latitude)) * COS(RADIANS("latitude")) * COS(RADIANS("longitude") - RADIANS($longitude)) + SIN(RADIANS($latitude)) * SIN(RADIANS("latitude")))) AS "distance"
FROM "locations"
HAVING "distance" < $distance
ORDER BY "distance" ASC
LIMIT 10;
```

If anyone can think of a better solution please let me know.

---

**I just [found this interesting link](http://www.thismuchiknow.co.uk/?p=71), I'll try it tomorrow.**

Answer (score 0):

Building off Alix's answer...

```
$db->sqliteCreateFunction('HAVERSINE', 'haversine', 2);
```

I would imagine that this would allow the query that you specified in your question to work.

Comment: I could use `HAVERSINE("latitude", "longitude")` but I've no idea how to work with the `$latitude` and `$longitude` PHP variables.