# Optimising a haversine formula SQL call in PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysql, math

I'm creating an MySQL call using PHP, I'm calculating distance using the haversine forumula:

```
SELECT name, id,
   (6371 * acos(cos(radians(' . $lat . ')) 
   * cos(radians(geoname.latitude)) 
   * cos(radians(geoname.longitude) - radians(' . $lon . ')) 
   + sin(radians(' . $lat . ')) 
   * sin(radians(geoname.latitude)))) AS distance
```

My question is; is it best to do all this calculation in SQL? This query searches a table with around 1000 records. Would it be more efficient to do some of the math in PHP rather than SQL? Is there a better way to optimise this query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the [Spherical Law of Cosines formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines), not the [Haversine Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) (which is slightly slower).

Doing the math in MySQL will probably be much faster, I advise you to [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096385/formulas-to-calculate-geo-proximity) I asked a while back, as for speed optimizations you should definitely read the excellent **[Geo Proximity Search with MySQL](http://www.arubin.org/files/geo_search.pdf)** paper, ***pay special attention to pages 8-14 and 19***.

Comment: can you please tell me which formula finally we got to use ?

Answer (score 2):

For a super fast MySQL indexer, Check out [Sphinx](http://www.sphinxsearch.com/).  It is extremely fast for finding what you need in your MySQL database, and does geo/distance calculations automatically.

Tutorial: [Geo/Spatial Search Using Sphinx Search and PHP](http://www.god-object.com/2009/10/20/geospatial-search-using-sphinx-search-and-php/)