# MySQL Lat/Lon radius search

Tags: mysql

I have a table with zipcode(int) and Location(point).  I'm looking for a MySql query or function.  Here is an example of the date.  I'd like to return 100 miles.

```
37922|POINT(35.85802 -84.11938)
```

Is there an easy query to achieve this?

Okay so I have this

```
select x(Location), Y(Location) FROM zipcodes
```

This will give me my two points, but how do i figure out whats within a distance of x/y?

Comment: What is wrong with using a function?

Comment: Unless you can show me a function that uses Point instead of decimal to defer the lat/lon I really don't want to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query to do this is not too hard, but is slow. You would want to use the Haversine formula.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

Converting that to SQL should not be too difficult, but calculating the distance for every record in a table gets costly as the data set increases.

The work can be significantly reduced by using a geohash function to limit the locus of candidate records. If accuracy is important, the Haversine formula can be applied to the records inside a geohash region.

If the mysql people never completed their GIS and Spatial extension, consider using ElasticSearch or MongoDB.

There is a pretty complete discussion here:
[Formulas to Calculate Geo Proximity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096385/formulas-to-calculate-geo-proximity)

Comment: thank you, but all of that is greek to me, i would really need to see an example on this one.

Comment: Google 'Haversine mysql'. Here is one: http://www.davidus.sk/web/main/index/article_id/8