# Find all lat/long under certain radius

Tags: math, gps, geospatial, latitude-longitude, spatial

I have set of lat/long which are stored in database and I have to find all the lat/long from the database which are lies between the given lat/long(e.g`latitude = 37.4224764,and longitude=-122.0842499`) and given radius(say 5miles).For this I need to do some addition and subtraction like:

`37.4224764 + 5mile
37.4224764 - 5mile`
and

`-122.0842499+5mile
-122.0842499-5mile`
But I don't know how the conversion works here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I know if a Lat,Lng point is contained within a circle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463907/how-do-i-know-if-a-lat-lng-point-is-contained-within-a-circle)

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478006/how-to-get-the-nearest-100-points-from-one-million-data-records-quickly/25813558#25813558

Answer (score 0):

You're a little vague in your requirements, do you just want to find out the coordinates of a point a certain distance from your current location in a given direction?  Or get a circle of a radius of a particular distance around your coordinates?  Or draw a line of a certain length from  your coordinates to another point a particular distance away?

I assume you'd probabaly want to use the [Geometry spherical library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical), e.g.

```
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(geometry.location.lat, geometry.location.lng);

var newLatLng = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(
    latLng,
    1000, 
    0
);
```

see also https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#Distance

PS: you need to add the geometry library parameter when loading the map:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry about vagueness in question, I have updated it.