# Closest Landmark to a Coordinate

Tags: geospatial

I have an app that displays maps. I would like to add a feature where the user can tap a location and have it it display information about the nearest landmark.

By landmark, I mean I have a set of predefined objects related to the app with latitude/longitude coordinates.

The app is able to convert X/Y screen coordinates to latitude/longitude.

The app already calculates the distance between two latitude/longitude coordinates.

Therefore, I could, through brute force, run through the list of landmarks and find the closest.

However, knowing this is a problem many applications have to face, I ask if there is a better technique to find the closest "landmark" to a latitude/longitude than brute force? Some kind of transform?

Comment: I would suggest looking at [Turf.js](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf), which supports various spatial functions, either client side or server-side, as nodejs. There is also a [leaflet plugin](http://leaflet-extras.github.io/RTree/examples/map.html) which supports R-tree indexing, if you want super fast lookup. OpenLayers3 also has support for R-trees. So, you have lots of choices, but hard to give an exact answer without knowing what software you are using.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478006/how-to-get-the-nearest-100-points-from-one-million-data-records-quickly/25813558#25813558

Comment: No database though. Interesting solution if you can use it.