# SQL Select: toilets within 50KM of a certain position?

Tags: sql, sqlite, distance

I need to find toilets around me, say within 50KM, and I have my position in term of latitude and longitude, toilets in database looks like:

```
Toilet ID (primary)
Address
Latitude
Longitude

my location: my_lat, my_lon
```

is it possible to construct a statement that returns all toilets within 50KM of (my_lat, my_lon)? Something like

```
select * from ToiletTable where 
  SQRT((Latitude - my_lat)^2 + (Longitude - my_lon)^2) < 50
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://johndyer.name/post/LatitudeLongitude-Distance-Calculation-in-SQL-Server.aspx ?

Comment: If only he had ended the question with "Please! I'm desperate!"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculating Great-Circle Distance with SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083182/calculating-great-circle-distance-with-sqlite)

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096385/formulas-to-calculate-geo-proximity

Comment: @Neil: Even though the actual gender is unknown to most of us, it was really nice of you to presume *him*.

Comment: @Andriy Seems a pretty safe presumption here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're not in the polar or pacific regions, i'd use:

```
where pow(2*(latitude - ?), 2) + pow(longitude - ?, 2) < distance
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [Haversine formula](http://Haversine%20formula)

Here are two full implementations, one in SQL: [Haversine Implementation](http://www.storm-consultancy.com/blog/development/code-snippets/the-haversine-formula-in-c-and-sql/)

EDIT:

[Here's a Haversine implementation of a UDF in SQLite](http://www.thismuchiknow.co.uk/?p=71). Unfortunately it's against the iPhone, but at least you have the exact implementation you need. Now you just need to determine how to plug it in.

SQL inlined below

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDistance]

(
  @lat1 Float(8),
  @long1 Float(8),
  @lat2 Float(8),
  @long2 Float(8)
)
RETURNS Float(8)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @R Float(8);
  DECLARE @dLat Float(8);
  DECLARE @dLon Float(8);
  DECLARE @a Float(8);
  DECLARE @c Float(8);
  DECLARE @d Float(8);
  SET @R = 6371; --This value is 6371 for kilometers, 3960 for miles.
  SET @dLat = RADIANS(@lat2 - @lat1);
  SET @dLon = RADIANS(@long2 - @long1);
  SET @a = SIN(@dLat / 2) * SIN(@dLat / 2) + COS(RADIANS(@lat1))
                    * COS(RADIANS(@lat2)) * SIN(@dLon / 2) * SIN(@dLon / 2);
  SET @c = 2 * ASIN(MIN(SQRT(@a)));
  SET @d = @R * @c;
  RETURN @d;
END
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the problem is, I am working on a SQLite database(ie a file) in Android, so I don't know if I can create my own function in addition to the database. Also, even with the function, how do I construct the SQL statement?

Comment: This link gives some info for Android development and Haversine. It might point you in the right direction. http://devdiscoveries.wordpress.com/2010/02/01/android-distance-between-two-points-on-the-earth/